# Prestashop 1.6: Pass new field value from checkout to order

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm struggling to pass an additional field value from checkout process to order, but have no luck. Maybe somebody can help me?

I've created input on checkout page, where the user enters a value. I need to write this value to new column in order, when the checkout is complete. I've extended ps_order table and order.php class, adding there our new field, but I have no idea how to pass the value from checkout template to order table.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store this value on a "cart" level and on "actionValidateOrder" to transfer it on "order" level. So extend ps_cart and Cart.php & ps_orders & Order.php and use the hook.